# .config $routeprovider angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, route-provider

i am using angularjs ..

mainhtml.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="demoapp">
<head>
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title>Angular js</title>
</head>
 <body> <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
     <div data-ng-view=""></div>

<div class="ng-view"></div>
    Name:<input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />{{name}}
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers|filter:name|orderBy:'city'">{{cust.name|uppercase}}-{{cust.city|lowercase}}</li>
    </ul>
        <script>
            var demoapp = angular.module('demoapp', []);
            demoapp.config(['$routeProvider',
          function ($routeProvider) {
         $routeProvider.
          when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'view1.html',
            controller: 'SimpleController'
        }).
        when('/partial2', {
            templateUrl: 'view2.html',
            controller: 'SimpleController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
  }]);
demoapp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
                $scope.customers = [{ name: 'aman', city: 'boom' },
                                     { name: 'ajay', city: 'reem dee' },
                                     { name: 'hood', city: 'meen' }
                ];
            });

        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

view1

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>View1</h2>
Name:
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.name" />
    <br />

   <ul>
       <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers|filter :filter.name|orderby"></li>
</ul>
    <br />
    Customer name:
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.name"/>
    <br />
    <br />
    Customer city:
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.city"/>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button data-ng-click="addCustomer()">Add customer</button>
    <br />
    <a href="#/view2">View2</a>
</div>
```

it works well before adding config($routeprovider) function,,,, routeprovider function is destroying the program... anyhelp to work it correctly

Comment: Please elaborate "destroying the program". Do you get an error? Any signs of what should work but doesn't? A common cause for `$routeProvider` specifically causing an error, is forgetting to include `angular-route.js`... but that's a stab in the dark! Tell us more!

Comment: {{cust.name|uppercase}}-{{cust.city|lowercase}}.... actually this is shown n browser instead of name and city name ...

Comment: Try running it in a browser that has a console and view it (F12 in Chrome, for example). Any errors reported there?

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] ... this is error in console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably

missed to include angular-route

```
<script data-require="angular-route@1.2.12" data-semver="1.2.12" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.12/angular-route.js"></script>
```

next step is to add dependency to ngRoute module, as below

```
var demoapp = angular.module('demoapp', ['ngRoute']);
```

enjoy to live sample : http://plnkr.co/edit/sgQGz0JHjKk4CRcoZSUf?p=preview

btw: more info here

1. https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-routeprovider-api
2. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/
3. [official angular page](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider)

Comment: i add <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script> to my code... is there still need to add your preffered angular-route

Comment: have you added 'ngRoute' module dependency? anyway see sample, pretty clear I believe. Does not care which lib you're adding.